# Help to understand by providing the meaning

Tags: trigonometry

Nowadays I am reading S.L Loney for trigonometry. In that book one line is written

> The quantity by which the cosine falls short of unity, i.e. $1-\cos A$,is called the **versed sine of $A$**. Also the quantity $1-\sin A$, by which the sine falls short of unity, is called the **coversed sine of $A$**.

Please help me to understand this.

Answer (score 0):

$\sin x$ and $\cos x$ are functions whose values range in the interval $(-1,1)$.

The [versine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Versine) (or versed sine) function is simply the function :

> > $1 - \cos x$.
>
> The *versine* of an angle equals $1$ minus its cosine.

The locution "to fall short of unity" means more or less : "what is missing to $1$", i.e. the complement to $1$ of the function.

---

See also [coversed sine](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/coversed_sine).